# start app in c++ popen() like VS Code does

Tags: c++, windows, shell, visual-studio-code

I am searching a way to start app using popen and do not wait until a process is over. For example like VS Code it does.

```
#include <string>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <memory>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string exec(const char *cmd)
{
    std::array<char, 128> buffer;
    string result;
    auto pipe = popen(cmd, "r");
    if (!pipe)
    {
        throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed!");
    }
    cout << "Opened pipe" << endl;

    while (!feof(pipe)){
        cout << "inside while loop" << endl;
        if (fgets(buffer.data(), 128, pipe) != nullptr){
            cout << "reading pipe" << endl;
            result += buffer.data();
        }
            
    }

    auto rc = pclose(pipe);
    return result;
}


int main(){
    exec("code");
    //exec(".\\launchApp.sh");
    cout << "finished" << endl;


}
```

This code will launch "VS Code" app and finish execution. "VS Code" will stay alive.
If I try to launch another app(I tried millions of apps), execution will be stuck on 'log' "inside while loop" until a user close the app. After closing, execution will be finished.

**What do I want to achieve?**

I want to execute the app in popen pipe, finish the execution of code, and leave app alive.

**What I tried?**

I already tried to execute in shell script(launchApp.sh) app in background and like cmd does "start .\launchApp.sh". Not working.
I read execution script of VS code, look like a usual thing.

Comment: Your program waits inside the loop forever because the pipe will block (just like stdin does) if you are waiting for input and there is nothing to read.  So don't call fgets unless you know there is something to read.  There are a variety of ways but one is to call `fcntl(pipe, F_SETFL, O_NONBLOCK)`

Comment: @JerryJeremiah , could you please correct my code in answers of this question? I am not sure how to implement your solution